# Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Ubuntu 12.04 - How do I change boot

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Ubuntu 12.04
The system still boots up 12.04
How do I boot up 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the timeout period as = 0. so GRUB not waiting for your choice. But you can do that by editing /etc/default/grub file.

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

that will give you a time of 10 sec.

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Boot_Display_Behavior)